# How to send react styled page as HTML with next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, sendgrid

I am using **SendGrid**, **NextJS**, **ReactJS** to send emails. The goal is to send a component to email as html.

1. The first step was to create the component:

```
// Basic component page
const TestingPageTemplate = ({ text }) => {



  return (
    <div style={{background: 'grey', color: 'orange', padding: '20px'}}>
      <h1>This is a email with stiling included</h1>
      <p>{ text }</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TestingPageTemplate
```

2. The second step is to create the endpoint in the API directory

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  
  // Get the env variables and set the API key...
  const {SG_EMAIL_API_KEY, FROM_EMAIL} = process.env;
  sgMail.setApiKey(SG_EMAIL_API_KEY);

  
  // Get the body params and create the send function
  const { toEmail, subject, html } = req.body;
  
  const msg = {
    to:       toEmail,
    from:     FROM_EMAIL,
    subject:  subject,
    html:     html
  };

  await sgMail.send(msg);
  res.json({ success: true });
}
```

3. In the main index page, I tried importing the Testing component and assign it to a variable as a function, or as a simple assignment process... The form uses a post method and the basic fetch function, which requires to stringfy the body... And here it comes the chain of problems..

I cannot stringfy the component because I will get an error saying I cannot convert a circular structure to JSON...

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property '_context' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'Provider' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at handleSendEmail (index.js?bee7:31:20)
```

The page with the sending email is the following:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import TestingPageTemplate from './templates/testing';

const HomePage = () => {



  const [toEmail, setToEmail] = useState('');
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const template = <TestingPageTemplate text={text}/>
  

  const message = {
    toEmail, subject, html: template
  };

  console.log(message);
  
  
  const handleSendEmail = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    try { 
      const result = await fetch('/api/hello', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(message)
      });
      console.log(result);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }


  return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSendEmail}>
            <input value={toEmail} onChange={e => setToEmail(e.target.value)} type='email' placeholder='To email' required/>
            <input value={subject} onChange={e => setSubject(e.target.value)} type='text' placeholder='Subject' required/>
            <input value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} type='text' placeholder='Write your message here....' required/>
            <button>Send email</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

I am trying to send a styled html react compoennt with sendgrid.
I tried to stringfy the component and set it as html field in the message object from sendgrid

```
  const message = {
    toEmail, subject, html: template
  };
```

**UPDATE**
With the help of ReactDOMServer, I used renderToStaticMarkup function to get the string html of the page...

```
const template = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<TestingPageTemplate text={text}/>);


  const message = {
    toEmail, subject, html: template
  };
```

Comment: If I will use `readFile` or if I browse for the element, I will not be able to pass a prop...

Comment: Did your update fix the issue? Does passing the contents of `renderToStaticMarkup` to the HTML template work?

Comment: Yes. The function get the static html tags for the whole page. But the 'MUST' in this case is that I need to do inline styling.

Comment: use the function, pass the required props and sent to the email the component. BTW, the sendgrid message key should be html.

Comment: Awesome! Do you mind posting an [answer to your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? It makes it much more visible so others can see it. Thanks!